# Getting Contextual Filters to exclude data for a matching filter

Tags: views

I have a site where I have 7 different geographic locations each with its own dedicated internet page showing, for example, forthcoming events for a particular location and other location specific data.

I have single common Panels node that acts as a template for all locations.  I pass the location identity in the url (www.mysite.com/location-name) and let Views and Contextual Filters populate the template according to the location identified in the url. All that works fine.

Now the bit that causes problems:  what I would like to do on each location's page is to list forthcoming events for the other locations, but exclude events for this location (since they are listed in more detail in a different View).

My theory was to use Contextual Filters to recognise the location from the argument in the url and then allow Views to collate all the events from all the other locations, except this one.  In other words I want to negate the contextual filter for the location argument in the url.

I am aware that Views provides an "exclude" for certain entities within contextual filters but is not providing the "exclude" button for this particular case using a textual argument.  Any help gratefully received!